# Jmeter delay test step while still allowing concurrent user login

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter, load

I've put together a jmeter script which Logs in to a portal then logs out. I want to simulate a wait time of 5 seconds after user logs in before they log out.

I have 500 users that are being read in from a CSV file. How do I add the delay of 5 seconds, without stopping the next user in the list from logging in?

Essentially my performance requirements for 500 users are:

- 30 minute duration
- 1 thread
- Ramp up of 1 user per second
- 5 second wait between login and logout

Can someone please assist with how i go about configuring the thread group properties to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should be simulating "think time" using [JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers), in your case [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) will be enough.

1. Configure your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) as follows:

   - Number of Threads: `500`
   - Ramp-up: `500`
   - Loop Count: `-1` (or tick `Forever`)
   - Scheduler Configuration -> Duration: `1800`
2. Add Constant Timer **as a child** of the "Logout" request and put `5000` into "Thread Delay" input

Example configuration:

[image: Login Logout Constant Timer JMeter]